# Cannot build DMG from .JAR with javapackager

Tags: java, java-8

I've tried building a DMG file from my jar by running the following command:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javapackager -deploy -native dmg -srcdir bin  -srcfiles MyTest.jar -srcfiles p -appclass com.example.Test -name MyTest -outdir deploy -outfile MyTest -v
```

But it keeps giving the following error message:

```
Bundler DMG Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
```

The funny thing is that if I copy the same folder into another Mac and run the same command, it will build DMG successfully. Therefore I believe it is something related to my config or system environment.

Do you have any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have declared a main class?

Comment: Yes. I can run the "jar" file directly without any issue

Comment: I have never used this command but is it expected that you have `-srcfiles p`? That seems like a strange file name…

Comment: @DidierL Yeah, it is a folder containing another third-party library which the main Java code is using

Answer (score 1):

I found that the order of the option `-srcfiles` is very important. The last `-srcfiles` should be the JAR file. In my case, I put `-srcfiles p` after `-srcfiles MyTest.jar`, that's why it did not work. Strangely it happened only to some Macs and some JDK, not all of them have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

javapackager was deprecated from java11, and I had the same issue on my local setup even with java8. There is a new tool called jpackage, here is a simple example:

```
jpackage -t dmg -n AppName --main-class main.core -i . --main-jar AppName.jar --icon ~/Downloads/path-toicons8-log-96.icns
```